# Ledger nano S interraction error: Ledger device: Incorrect length (0x6700)

Tags: web3js, ledger-nano-s

```
const LedgerWalletProvider = require('@ledgerhq/web3-subprovider');
const createLedgerSubprovider = LedgerWalletProvider.default;
const TransportNodeHid = require('@ledgerhq/hw-transport-node-hid');
const ProviderEngine = require('web3-provider-engine');
const RpcSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const engine = new ProviderEngine();
const getTransport = () => TransportNodeHid.default.create();
const ledger = createLedgerSubprovider(getTransport, { networkId: 3 });
engine.addProvider(ledger);
engine.addProvider(new RpcSubprovider({ rpcUrl: 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3' + infuraKey }));
engine.start();

const web3 = new Web3(engine);
web3.eth.getAccounts((err, res) => {
    console.log(err.message); // Ledger device: Incorrect length (0x6700)
});
```

I want to create a node app with Ledger Nano S to keep my keys and sign transaction.
This is my code ^, but I get the following error

> Ledger device: Incorrect length (0x6700)